# Angular 2 get routes params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How I can get params this way:

```
mydomain.com/?token=MY_TOKEN&some=test
```

How I can get the `token` and the `some` from the URL to my angular 2 component?
I tried:

```
this.route.params
    .subscribe((params) => {
        this.token = params['token'];
        this.some = params['some'];
    });
```

Comment: ...and what happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get query params from url in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are query params you are looking for

```
this.route.queryParams
.subscribe((params) => {
    this.token = params['token'];
    this.some = params['some'];
});
```