# Access url parameters of pwa address

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, url-parameters, progressive-web-apps

I am new to ionic 2. After a searching everywhere I can not find a direct answer given the following scenario:

1. I am building a PWA with ionic 2 (because I will later develop hybrid versions of this app)
2. the address where users will find and access my app will be a standard domain like `https://welcometotheapp.com?viewid=0101018737abcdefg`
3. I am using ionic 2, recently installed on windows 10
4. I have started a new blank app project
5. My question is NOT related to navigation.

My question is how do I go about accessing the  url parameter `viewid`? I need this parameter so that the app send it to my server side REST api and get the right json data. My users receive the url with the parameter as a link by SMS. 
I have tried to make use of several suggestions like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-to-get-query-params-from-angular2?)

But I'm spinning my wheels. I've also watched quite a number of youtube vids from Josh Morony and others but again nothing directly related.

Can someone help with this question? As a newbie, it would be very helpful if code snips were annotated with what code goes in what file given the ionic2 blank template structure. Thanks peeps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try plain old javascript. I dont think this is anything specific to ionic. And because it is not primarily navigation based then the `NavParams` would not work, i am guessing.

In `.js` you can do a `split` like so

```
let myParam = location.search.split('viewid=')[1];
```

Note that if there is no `viewId=` then the variable will be undefined. Here are the docs for [location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search)

Comment: Thanks, I have succeesfully used javascript for this kind of thing before. So as far as structure, if I created a .js file, like "readurl.js", where would I place it in the application file tree and how would I reference/call it? Reading the parameter from the url is the 1st thing the app needs to do after loading. The json data will be displayed on home.html.

Comment: I would suggest adding it to the `app.component.ts` in the constructor. Or depending how you are going to manipulate the data the `home.ts` in the constructor or the `ionViewDidLoad()` function

Comment: thanks for your help. in my case I ended up adding it to my home.ts in the ionViewDidLoad() function because I only want to retrieve the parameter(s) the on the initial load. It is my understanding from the documentation that if placed in the constructor, it would run every time the page loads. In my case, this is undesirable. Again, many thanks!

Comment: @gerdi if the url is in the form https://welcometotheapp.com/astringgoeshere/?key1=value&key2=value2 and I want to read url after .com/. will it work? or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `Location` from `@angular/common`. So I believe is worth post another answer:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

...

public urlParams: any;

constructor(..., public location: Location) {
    this.initializeURLParams();
    console.log(this.urlParams);
}

initializeURLParams() {
  const path = this.location.path(true),
    hasParams = /\?(.+?\=.+){1}/;
  let params;

  if (hasParams.test(path)) {
    params = {};
    path.split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(both => {
      let e = both.split('=');
      params[e[0]] = e[1];
    });
  }

  this.urlParams = params;
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, in the browser. This.location.path (true) returned "" . However I only tested it with ionic:serve, not sure what would happen in production. What worked though is this: location._platformStrategy._platformLocation.location.search;

Comment: Update, the above was when the path does not have # hash. When it does location.path works fine