# Get data from link in Ionic 3 Web App

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

**Scenario:**

I have an Ionic 3 Web app, which opens for this link http://localhost:8100. I need to pass a value with the link (i.e http://localhost:8100/index.html?cell=1234567890) and the ionic app while loading the app, fetches the cell value.

**What i have done:**

Seriously I have no idea, where to start. I used `NavParams` like this,

```
this.cell = this.navParams.get('cell');
```

and opened the app like http://localhost:8100/index.html?cell=1234567890, the app is opened successfully, but i'm getting an undefined value.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: well, Ionic can be used as a web app, it supports PWA. My issue is, I need to pass a value to my home page from a link not from another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer from the official documentation, [IonicPage Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).

so i have used

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'feedback/:cell'
})
```

and in constructor,

```
this.cell = this.navParams.get('cell');
```

now when i called this link `http://localhost:8100/#/feedback/1234567890`
and i get the number. everything is working fine now.

Thank you for your responses, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is what you want but you can send params like this

```
this.navCtrl.push(ChildPage, {
        cell: value
    });
```

on Child page Constructor or

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.cell= this.navParams.get('cell');
    console.log(this.cell);
}
```

Comment: This works when I'm navigating from first page to second. The parameters are passed from first page and fetched in second page. But I need the parameters fetched at the first page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try plain old javascript. I dont think this is anything specific to ionic. And because it is not primarily navigation based then the NavParams would not work, i am guessing, you can do `split` like so

```
let myParam = location.search.split('cell=')[1];
```

Ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619323/access-url-parameters-of-pwa-address)