# Extract more than one parameter from URL with Angular

Tags: angular, url, typescript

I am making a simple Angular (version 4) application with TypeScript.

I have an URL that looks like this:
`www.example.com/api/1/countries/Italy/`

And I want to get `1` and `Italy` from this URL and assign them to variables.

I tried with `ActivatedRoute` like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.router
        .queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
           this.id = +params[''];
           this.country = +params[''];
        });
}
```

Where `id`and `country` are my private variables I want to assign with the values from the URL. But I don't know how exactly to proceed...

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Please look at solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146396/6036154)

Comment: `1` and `Italy` aren't query parameters, they're route parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URL example you don't use query parameters. So the code to get values from the ActivatedRoute could look like this:

```
 this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 this.country = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('country');
```

This code assumes that you have configured your routes with params named id and country, e.g.

```
 {path: 'api/:id', component: CompA}
   ...
 {path: 'countries/:country', component: CompB}
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I have only one single Component. Does something like this make sense: `{path: '/api/:id/countries/:country/', component: IndexPageComponent}` ?

Comment: Yes, it'll work. you may not need the leading forward slash though.

Answer (score 0):

you can access url using **DOCUMENT** and parse it.

**component.ts**

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
    console.log(document.location.href);
  }
```