# Pass and read query parameters in angular 2

Tags: angular

How to pass and read query parameters in angular 2, for example
http://localhost:3000/index.html?page=235 or http://localhost:300/?page=235 to get 235?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get query params from url in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2)

Comment: I get this error: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Comment: @baraka How did you solve the problem of  "No provider for ActivatedRoute!"  I am facing the same issue and not finding any relevant source to address it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get param like that.

**Example**

```
 userId: number;
     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                    private router: Router) {
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
                (params: any) => {
                    if (params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
                        this.userId = +params.id;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

see for more details [router](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter)

Comment: the problem is that i want to use index page

Answer (score 0):

Try This .

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to params
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let page= params['page'];
        console.log(page);
      });
  }

}
```