# Subscribing to query string parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I've seen quite a few examples of subscribing to query string parameters in Angular 2+ but I can't seem to get it to work

e.g. [How get query params from url in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2)

Here is my code:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  private a: boolean = true;
  private b: boolean = true;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute)  {
  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams:any) => {
      this.a = queryParams.a;
      this.b = queryParams.b;
     });
```

The problem I have is that `this` does not appear to refer to my component to setting `a` and `b` which I want to use to drive `*ngIf` statements does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to define the type `queryParams : Params`

Comment: `this.route` probably undefined. Try to define it as instance member: `constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)` - pay attention to added `private` modifier. Also it is recommended to use `queryParamMap` instead of `queryParams`

Answer (score 11):

The below code is for Angular 5.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private a: boolean;
  private b: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)  {
  this.a = true;
  this.b = true;
  ...
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
      this.a = queryParams['a'];
      this.b = queryParams['b'];
  });
```

Could you try and check if it works?

Answer (score 3):

It works for me...

```
let comp = this;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
  comp.a = queryParams['a'];
  comp.b = queryParams['b'];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // Example http://google.com?foo=bar#hash
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(frag => {
      // Result: 'hash'
      console.log('Fragment: ', frag);
    });
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
      /**
       * result: 'bar'
       */
      console.log('Data: ', queryParams);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem  is your a and b are PRIVATE .. you have to make them PUBLIC top use in your html like:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  public a: boolean = true; //<-- PUBLIC
  public b: boolean = true;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute)  {
  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams:any) => {
      this.a = queryParams.a;
      this.b = queryParams.b;
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Sadly this didn't work. Can't see what I am missing!

Comment: Are your sure your queryParams.a; is a boolean ? ..can you maybe check ? (maybe it's 'true' ..so a string .. cause it came from a url ... can post also yur html with ngIf ?

Comment: Adjusted the comparison to this: this.a= (queryParams.a === 'true'); still not working for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

You are losing 'this'. You should create function and bind it to this component and put it on subscribe callback.
 Also you can save your this like 
`const self = this`