# How to get Query Parameters in the Angular component

Tags: angular, url-parameters

I followed this answer: [How to get query params from url in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2/35688288), and am not sure how they were able to test by entering `http://localhost:4200?test=hi`. Please give advice - this does not work for me.

I have an `AppComponent` and a router which routes to `OrderComponent`. I need to get the query parameter from the URL in the `AppComponent` and pass the same to the `OrderComponent`.

Comment: did you follow all the answers. none of the answer worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ngOnInit method of your component class you can do the following:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(){
      this.route.queryParamMap
                .map((params: Params) => params.params)
                .subscribe( (params) => {
                     if(params && params['test']){
                        let testQueryParamVal = params['test'];
                     }
                 });
  }
```

Comment: yes this worked
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(map => console.log("map",map.get("ordertype")));

But I am able to test with URL as 
http://localhost:4200/OrderMgmtComponent/red

When I give like below, it shows error
http://localhost:4200/OrderMgmtComponent?ordertype="red"


ERROR:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'OrderMgmtComponent'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'OrderMgmtComponent'
Any idea why it show the error ?

Comment: You're getting this error because you've not defined that route with only `OrderMgmtComponent`. Be aware that in angular `route params` and `route query params` are two different things.

Comment: Pls see this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6410
This says we cannot test URL with http://localhost:4200?a=b