# Send data with router link

Tags: html, angular, webstorm

I'm trying to passing the data from one page to another routing page using `[queryParams]="{'usd':usd, 'count' :country, 'name' :name}"` from the routing button. it's perfectly working but there is an error in my console.

```
ERROR in src/app/hairstylist-profile/hairstylist-profile.component.ts(18,40): error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'.
src/app/hairstylist-profile/hairstylist-profile.component.ts(20,42): error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'.
src/app/hairstylist-profile/hairstylist-profile.component.ts(22,41): error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'.
```

this is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hairstylist-profile',
  templateUrl: './hairstylist-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hairstylist-profile.component.css'],
})
export class HairstylistProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  name;
  usd;
  count;
  constructor(private  route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const usd = this.route.queryParams.value.usd;
    this.usd = usd;
    const count = this.route.queryParams.value.count;
    this.count = count;
    const name = this.route.queryParams.value.name;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

there is an error in **value** keyword. So how can solve?

Comment: Read the error message; you don't have the params, you have *an observable of them*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get query params from url in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may Help you

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.route
               .queryParams
               .subscribe(params => {
                   // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
                 this.usd = params['usd'] || 0;
                 this.count = params['count'] || 0;
                 this.name = params['name'] || ';
                 });
}
```

You cannot use .value,you must subscribe query parmas

Comment: Just as an update for anyone who stumbles on this later: You can access route params without subscribing to an observable via `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` - eg. `this.route.snapshot.queryParams['usd']`

Note this obviously will not update when you change routes. Always recommended to use the observable. Piping these query values to a `switchMap()` to make API calls or using the `| async` pipe in your template is an even better option than subscribing.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 4.0.0**

See Angular docs for more details  https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

**ORIGINAL**

Using a service is the way to go. In route params you should only pass data that you want to be reflected in the browser URL bar.

See also  [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service)

The router shipped with RC.4 re-introduces `data`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

and ..

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch : 'full'},
  {path : 'heroes', component : HeroDetailComponent, data : {some_data : 'some value'}}
];
```

and ..

```
class HeroDetailComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

See also the Plunker at  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9757#issuecomment-229847781