# How to show Angular components based on the value of query string?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, query-string, angular-routing, angular5

I'm using the Angular 4/5 currently and let’s say I have 2 components **Component 1** and **Component 2**. Now, I've been given a task that if the URL is  http://localhost:4200/?property1=value1, then Component 1 will be displayed and if the URL is http://localhost:4200/?property1=value2, then Component 2 will be displayed.

Since I'm a beginner in Angular, therefore, I'm facing problems in these two tasks.

1. Finding the values of property1 (i.e. value1 and value 2) from the query string each time.
2. After finding the value, how to define a logic i.e. which component to show?

Although I find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2), I'm unable to find the logic for using the value to see the component. Please help.

**Edit**: On working through the @Osman Cea's answer, this is the error I'm getting:

```
null: ERROR
null: Error: StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]: 
__zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask {_zone: Zone, runCount: 0, _zoneDelegates: null, …}
message: "StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!"
ngDebugContext: DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: Object, …}
ngErrorLogger: function () { … }
ngTempTokenPath: null
ngTokenPath: Array(1) []
stack: "Error: StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
    at _NullInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1189:19)
    at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1477:24)
    at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1419:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1290:20)
    at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1477:24)
    at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1419:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1290:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11074:25)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12306:16)
    at resolveDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12804:45)"
__proto__: Object {constructor: , name: "Error", message: "", …}
null: ERROR CONTEXT
null: DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}
component: null
componentRenderElement: app-root
context: null
elDef: Object {nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, …}
elOrCompView: Object
elView: Object {def: Object, parent: null, viewContainerParent: null, …}
injector: Injector_
nodeDef: Object {nodeIndex: 1, parent: Object, renderParent: Object, …}
nodeIndex: 1
providerTokens: Array(1)
references: Object
renderNode: app-root
view: Object {def: Object, parent: null, viewContainerParent: null, …}
__proto__: Object {elOrCompView: <accessor>, injector: <accessor>, component: <accessor>, …}
null: Error: StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference of your `queryParams` Observable by injecting the `ActivatedRoute` in your parent component and subscribing to it. Let's say you have the following `app.component.ts`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeParam">
      <component-one *ngSwitchCase="'value1'"></component-one>
      <component-two *ngSwitchCase="'value2'"></component-two>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  activeParam: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.activeParam = params.property1)
  }
}
```

What you get in the `params` argument is a plain regular object with the following signature `{ [key: string]: any }` where key is the name of the param, and the value... well, the value of the given param. You can get a hold of that value inside the `activeParam` property and use the `ngSwitch` directive to decide which component to render.

You could also do this with Observables and the `async` pipe like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeParam$ | async">
      <component-one *ngSwitchCase="'value1'"></component-one>
      <component-two *ngSwitchCase="'value2'"></component-two>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  activeParam$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activeParam$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(pluck('property1'))
  }
}
```

In this case you're *extracting* the value assigned to the `property1` key in the object you get when subscribing to the observable, this way it will safely ignore those `queryParams` you don't actually need to observe, and the *value* of the Observable will either be `value1` or `value2`, or whatever it's after the `=` in your url.

Comment: Both of these methods didn't work for me as I got the `Error: StaticInjectorError[ActivatedRoute]` whenever I tried to opened the link http://localhost:4200/?property1=value1 or the one with the value2. How to fix this error?

Comment: I've posted the complete error message trace in the question. Please see it.

Comment: I guess this is because you have to import the `RouterModule` into your main `AppModule`

Comment: I imported the RouterModule in my AppModule as `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` and the code was working successfully. But one thing which I can't understand is that why it is working even on providing the empty array routes as `const routes: Routes = [ ];`. Can you please clear this doubt of mine?