# How to pass optional Router Parameter with preserved URL in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router

I have some specific requirement in that have to work with Existing URL. Existing URL's are already well indexed and used for promotions and many campaigns so no chance to modify it.

Existing URLs is like - `www.xyz.com/search//65.5445/-122.56454/Listing-name/All`

While In Angular defining URL like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SearchpagesComponent ,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'search/:schkey/:lat/:lng/:name/:filter', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule',
        // here schkey is optinal just required blank slashes 
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and in Router link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/search/','','37.7749295','-122.41941550000001','San-Francisco','All']" > Goto Search Page </a>
```

Current : Above code is working, If I click on Routerlink defined anchor. its redirecting and component being loaded, but **on refreshing the page component is not loading** and redirecting to root URL.

Expected:`www.xyz.com/search//37.7749295/-122.41941550000001/San-Francisco/` on direct link or refreshing page component should be loaded. And double slashes `search//` should be preserved.

For Reproducing - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes-6ydor6

Github Issue - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32853

Comment: Could you provide stackblitz?

Comment: To workaround you can replace empty param with **_**

Comment: @phat.huynh _ underscore will not work, as all pages indexed. and promotional links active

Comment: Consider using URL query parameters

Comment: @PhatHuynh https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes-6ydor6

Comment: I think use URL query parameters is better

Comment: @PhatHuynh If not having such requirement definitely going with that

Comment: Can't you just use your webserver to do 301 redirections? e.g. redirect `/search//x/y/z` to `/search/dummy/x/y/z`?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because `:schkey` is left empty.

You can define multiple routes with and without certain parameters.

```
{
    path: 'search/:schkey/:lat/:lng/:name/:filter',
    component: SearchpageComponent
},
{
    path: 'search/:lat/:lng/:name/:filter',
    component: SearchpageComponent
}
```

Basically, instead of:

```
http://.../search//37.7749295/-122.41941550000001/San-Francisco/All
```

your URL would be:

```
http://.../search/37.7749295/-122.41941550000001/San-Francisco/All
```

Comment: hi @Electron , this is not requirement I know that can be achieve by skipping , but have specific requirement to preserve slashes.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for now. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3957#issuecomment-208345337. Even tho, the report is very old. A possible solution could be to intercept the navigation and if the argument is null, replace it with some 'default' value but I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no problem for url rewrite when hard refresh, this solution works as expected.
[example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-child-routes-3h4exp?file=null)

i used this in main.ts before bootstraping the app.

```
 const __stripTrailingSlash = (Location as any).stripTrailingSlash;
(Location as any).stripTrailingSlash = function _stripTrailingSlash(url: string): string {
  if(url.indexOf('//') > -1){
    url = url.replace('//','/');
    return url;
  }
  return /[^\/]\/$/.test(url) ? url : __stripTrailingSlash(url);
}
```

idea from github issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16051

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct and can be work. but what issue happens with this, without slashes google crawler will consider it as a new page and all generated indexes till date will be losen. This is one risk factor here.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify several routes for one component/module. One route will with this parameter and the second one - without.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SearchpagesComponent ,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'search/:schkey/:lat/:lng/:name/:filter', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule',
        path: 'search//:schkey/:lat/:lng/:name/:filter', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Or you can pass them via query string, like here [How to get query params from url in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-to-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular-2) in this case you do not need to specify them in your routes config

Answer (score 0):

**No need to create multiple routes.**

Instead of this
`<a [routerLink]="['/search/','','37.7749295','-122.41941550000001','San-Francisco','All']" > Goto Search Page </a>`

**You can create one method like this**

`goToPage() {
this.router.navigate(['/product-list'], { queryParams: {searchParms?.schkey},{ searchParms?.lat}, {searchParms?.lng} , { searchParms?.name}, { searchParms?.filter} });
}`

**You can create one object in your ts file call searchParms with fields and use it.**

**And create route like
const routes**
`Routes = [ { path: '', component: SearchpagesComponent , children: [ { path: 'search', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchModule', // here schkey is optinal just required blank slashes } ] } ];`

Comment: There is no problem with routerLink on page refresh it's not working

Comment: That may be caused because of routes issues that is not match with route which you create. If you pass parms in queryParms then it will not break.

Comment: And on your results page you need to het that parms and get your data from backend

Comment: You create that route with mandatory parameter and if you refresh your page. At that time some parms are missing in your route so it will break.

Comment: Yes exactly, route is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying '' for :schkey in `<a [routerLink]="['/search/',nondefinedvariable,'37.7749295','-122.41941550000001','San-Francisco','All']" > Goto Search Page </a>` you can specify a variable name that is not defined in the component so when the url forms it will look like  *http://..../search/undefined/37....*
which will forward you to the same page even if you refresh it, But you will need to check in the SearchComponent for the schkey value that it should not be equals to `'undefined'` if you are using for any functionality, Its a hack, but can fulfils the case

Comment: This is not the question. the only requirement is if I paste URL in browser www.xyz.com/search//65.5445/-122.56454/Listing-name/All component should load which is not working, the route is braking after double slashes.