# Angular check URL with specific format

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular-router

I want to check my URL that has exactly a **specific** format.
I have this URL

```
www.example.com?rt=12365
```

I want to check if income URL has below format

```
?rt= number
```

then do something.
I use the router like my below code:

```
const queryParams = router.url
```

but I don't know **how** to check it. I'm new to typescript and angular, please help me

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146396/2389923

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `queryParams`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params.rt);
        if(!isNaN(params.rt)){
            console.log("URL Match");
        }else{
            console.log("URL does not Match");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this code just gets rl to me. I need to check that if URL exactly has "rt=number" format

Comment: you can check `if(params.rt)` for value of rt is exist or no

Comment: should I check like this:  ``has("rt")``?

Comment: so how to check that front of rt is number?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

 }

 if (this.route.snapshot.queryParams['rt']) {
      if ( !isNaN(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['rt']) && angular.isNumber(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['rt'])) 
       {
         }
 }
```

Hope useful for you

Comment: How do I check that there is a number in front of the rt and nothing more؟

Comment: @heliyarb also might be worth checking out Lodash, quite a nice library with a lot of useful functions: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNumber

Comment: what is angular in this code? I get Cannot find name 'angular' error

Comment: import {isNumeric} from "rxjs/util/isNumeric" var isNumber = isNumeric(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['rt']) cehck this

Comment: add it but still has an error. I think it's for angular.js. I use angular 8.

Comment: yeh delete angular and replace by isNumeric